# Laravel sync with 3 column

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a table called `relations` (business relations). A relation can have other relations (business relations).

So I've got a pivot table. However there are 2 type's of relations `internal` and `external`.

My table structure looks like this:

```
relation_parent_id
relation_child_id
type
```

So right now I've got this:

**Controller:**

```
$relation->syncRelations($request->relations_internal, 'internal');
$relation->syncRelations($request->relations_external, 'external');
```

**Relation Model:**

```
public function syncRelations($relations, $type)
{
    $relations = collect($relations)->mapWithKeys(function($relation) use ($type) {
        return [$relation => ['type' => $type]];
    })->toArray();

    $this->relations()->sync($relations);

    return $this;
}
```

The problem is that it sync's with `relation_parent_id` and `relation_child_id`, but in my case it needs to sync with the `type` as well.

Because right now they override each other.

Let's say the request contains this:

```
1
2
internal

1
2
external
```

I will end up with one of them.

If you have more questions please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at [Polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: @MateiMihai yes I've though about that but `internal` and `external` are no models in this case.

Comment: Someone please ??

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?